# Compare 2 datetime in PHP from mysql to be viewed in android

Tags: php, android, mysql, datetime, compare

I have an android app that lets the user to create a quiz to be saved in the database (mysql). Creating a quiz is now OK. I can also view the quizzes. But since in my TABLE quiz I have a COLUMN start_on and end_on which is both a datetime. I want the user to view the data only if start_on > now() and end_on < now(). Or to make it short, between the two datetime.

```
TABLE quiz
id   start_on              end_on
1    2016-06-22 10:30:00   2016-06-22 11:00:00
```

my initial php script in viewing the data

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
require_once('dbConnect.php');
$sql = "SELECT * FROM quiz;
$r = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$result = array();
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($r);
array_push($result,array(
"id"=>$row['id']
"start_on"=>$row['start_on']
"end_on"=>$row['end_on']
)); 
echo json_encode(array('result'=>$result));
mysqli_close($con);
```

Im thinking of making a php script that will get start_on, and a separate php script that will get end_on. Then compare them in Java android part.

Im also thinking of this format in PHP but I dont know how to do it. Please help me, thanks.

```
if(start_on >= now() && end_on <= now()) {
    SELECT * FROM quiz WHERE id = '$id';
    //the user can view the quiz in his android app
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is what you are expecting

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE start_on > date('Y-m-d H:i:s')  AND end_on >= date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
```

Change the conditions as per your needs;

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I edited your answer and came up with this, SELECT * FROM quiz WHERE start_on <= now() AND end_on >= now(). This query works like charm. But thanks, you gave me the hint on how to do it =)

Comment: glad it helped... happy coding;